# notifyDataSetChanged() refresh the whole layout

Tags: android, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

I didn't describe the question in a good way, so I edit the question to be clear.

I am so confused about this: I wrote a **RelativeLayout** with a **DragViewGroup** and a **gridview**, and I noticed that every time when I used **notifyDatasetChanged()** method would cause the **DragViewGroup** do the redrawing thing.And the **DragViewGroup** extends from **LinearLayout** which uses **ViewDragHelper**, so I could not maintain the position already scrolled to.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<com.xxxx.DragViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/dragview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3f83f7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="665dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="310dp"
            android:id="@+id/mainview"
            >

            ...

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="355dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
            layout="@layout/fake_panel" />

    </LinearLayout>
</com.xxxx.DragViewGroup>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/btn_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <com.xxxx.UniversalSeekBar
        ....
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DragViewGroup code:

```
public class DragViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
     private ViewDragHelper viewDragHelper;
     private View mainView;
     private int mainHeight;



public DragViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public DragViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

public DragViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)         {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView();
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mainView = getChildAt(0);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mainHeight = mainView.findViewById(R.id.mainview).getMeasuredHeight();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return viewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    viewDragHelper.processTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (viewDragHelper.continueSettling(true)) {
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}

private void initView() {
    viewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, callback);
}

private ViewDragHelper.Callback callback = new ViewDragHelper.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId) {
        return mainView == child;
    }

    @Override
    public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
        return top;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
        super.onViewReleased(releasedChild, xvel, yvel);
        if (mainView.getTop() > -500) {
            viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(mainView, 0, 0);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(DragViewGroup.this);

        } else {
            viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(mainView, 0, -mainHeight);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(DragViewGroup.this);

        }
    }

};

}
```

Once I use the notifyDatasetChanged() method to update the gridview, my DragViewGroup will slide to the original position itself although it has been dragged before. Apparently the method draw the whole layout instead of only drawing gridview itself.

I need to maintain the dragged position of DragViewGroup, I have tried that override onDraw method in DragViewGroup like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   // set isDragged label in onViewReleased()   
   if (isDragged) {
      viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(main, 0, -mainHeight);
   }
}
```

It works, but there is a visible sliding process which I don't want.
Hope someone could help me.Thanks very much.

Comment: ScrollView has no such method for `notifyDataSetChanged()`; this method belongs to [the BaseAdapter class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()), and is typically associated with ListViews, GridViews or RecyclerViews.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I mean that I use notifyDataSetChange() to update the GridView only, while the scrollView in the same activity has been redrawed either.

Comment: Invoking that method on your adapter will cause a layout pass in your GridView so that all list items can be measured and placed within the layout. If the size of your GridView is exact, the layout pass shouldn't continue up your layout hierarchy. Perhaps you've provided `wrap_content` as one of its dimensions?

Comment: It would be useful to have a better understanding of your layout hierarchy in general. Is your GridView _inside_ a ScrollView?

Comment: Nah, they are separated. I will update the question and provide my layout xml.

Comment: Oh, right. I will try that later.@David

Answer (score 0):

Store ScrollValue at the time of the scrolling the view, and just use setSelectionMethod on your gridview

```
gridview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count = gridview.getCount();
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (gridview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - 1) {
                        scrollPos = <positionOfList>;
                    }
                }
}
});
```

Here enter your last position insted of "positionOfList"
And just after calling notifydatasetChanged() call gridview.setSelection(scrollPos)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. But I just wonder why the scrollview being redrawed either. I thought notifyDataSetChanged only refresh listview/gridview itself.

Comment: If your gridview is inside ScrollView then do not do that, gridview having it's own scroll view, you do not have to put scrollview on the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Just use bellow code in class that you update display:

```
 int index = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = myList.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    myList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my minimum API level is 11, I find that the setSelectionFromTop method requires at least API 21.